# Transfer information between databases where an attribute was split using C# and VS

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to build a solution to update an older database with information from a newer database. In the new database they deleted an attribute and separated that attribute into 5 other attributes. The problem with this is when I try to build the project it fails because it doesn't know what that attribute is.

For example

The old DB might have `User.FName`, `User.MName`, and `User.LName` and I need to turn it into `User.Name`.(reversed for simplicities sake. It doesn't change the issue)

When I try to do something like `User.Name = User.FName + ' ' + User.MName + ' ' + User.LName` and build it, it will fail because it doesn't know what `User.Name` is.

When the resulting .exe file is run it should work because it is using a different database that does have `User.Name`, however it won't build because the current one I am using does not. Any idea how I can get around this or have it build with errors? Also I am not using Entity Framework in this project, I am using Dapper.

Comment: Does dapper read the database as part of the build? If not, then I can't see how this would be an issue. The only errors (I think) that cause a build to fail are compilation errors and (maybe) pre-build failures. But I'm not familiar with dapper, so maybe it's checking the db during the build.

Comment: What's the actual error that prevents compilation?  If the schemas are different then I suspect you'd need to use different framework code to access them, not re-use the same code.  In the DAL layer this may mean a decent amount of repeated code, but as long as it's abstracted behind the central domain model that shouldn't be a big deal.  For example, you might have a `User` model and two `UserRepository` implementations, one which saves it directly and one which translates it into a slightly modified `UserDTO` inside the DAL to save that directly.

Comment: Is "User.Name" the name of the field in your old db or the name of a member in your solution? Or both? Also try changing out `User.Name = ...` to `User{ Name{ get { string x = User.FName + @" " + User.MName + @" " + User.LName; return x; } } }` this will make it so when you call User.Name it's the current values and not the static values from runtime or another time. Also changing ' ' for space to a verbatim whitespace @" ".

Comment: Error 1 'User' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'User' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: CalebB the example above is an example like the project. Almost everything about it has been changed to protect corporate assets, but thank you. It's still helpful to me because I haven't had to write one of those yet in C#, I'm a C# newb coming from Ruby.